# Tips to refactor code : very repetitive code

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple problem : my code is too repetitive. It works, but it could be much cleaner. I don't know exactly where to start.

I'd like to learn to work better, and I'd really like someone to help me with it.

Here's the 2 bits of my code that are very repetitive (everything I've done myself) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Setup your Lazy Line element.
  // see README file for more settings
  $('#drawing1').lazylinepainter({
      'svgData': dr1,
      'strokeWidth': 1.2,
      'strokeColor': '#65615a',
      'onComplete': function () {

      }
    })

  $('#drawing2').lazylinepainter({
      'svgData': dr2,
      'strokeWidth': 1.2,
      'strokeColor': '#65615a',
      'onComplete': function () {

      }
    })

  $('#drawing3').lazylinepainter({
      'svgData': dr3,
      'strokeWidth': 1.2,
      'strokeColor': '#65615a',
      'onComplete': function () {

      }
    })

  $('#drawing4').lazylinepainter({
      'svgData': dr4,
      'strokeWidth': 1.2,
      'strokeColor': '#65615a',
      'onComplete': function () {

      }
    })

  $('#drawing5').lazylinepainter({
      'svgData': dr5,
      'strokeWidth': 1.2,
      'strokeColor': '#65615a',
      'onComplete': function () {

      }
    })

  // Paint your Lazy Line, that easy!

})

})(jQuery);
```

Second part of the code:

```
var eventsFiredDr1 = 0;

var drawing1 = function () {
  if(eventsFiredDr1 == 0) {

    $('#drawing1').lazylinepainter('paint');

    eventsFiredDr1++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
  }
}

var eventsFiredDr2 = 0;

var drawing2 = function () {
  if(eventsFiredDr2 == 0) {

    $('#drawing2').lazylinepainter('paint');

    eventsFiredDr2++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
  }
}

var eventsFiredDr3 = 0;

var drawing3 = function () {
  if(eventsFiredDr3 == 0) {

    $('#drawing3').lazylinepainter('paint');

    eventsFiredDr3++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
  }
}

var eventsFiredDr4 = 0;

var drawing4 = function () {
  if(eventsFiredDr4 == 0) {

    $('#drawing4').lazylinepainter('paint');

    eventsFiredDr4++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload

  }
}

var drawing5 = function () {
  if(eventsFiredDr5 == 0) {

    $('#drawing5').lazylinepainter('paint');

    eventsFiredDr5++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload

  }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
  if($(window).width() < 820) {

    $("svg").hide()
    $(".fallback").show()
    $("#drawing2").css("height", "auto")
  }
});

if($(window).width() > 820) {

  $(".fallback").hide()

  $(window).scrollStopped(function () {
    if($("#drawing1").is(":within-viewport")) {
      drawing1()
    }

    if($("#drawing2").is(":within-viewport")) {
      drawing2()
    }

    if($("#drawing3").is(":within-viewport")) {
      drawing3()
    }

    if($("#drawing4").is(":within-viewport")) {
      drawing4()
    }

    if($("#drawing5").is(":within-viewport")) {
      drawing5()
    }

  });
```

( I know I should put DOM elements in variables, but I planned on doing it when I would refactor the code. )

My first guess would be creating an array but.. No idea how to use it in my code. (I'm a big beginner)

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 4):

For the code repetition you can use

```
$(function () { // shorter form of document-ready
    $.each([dr1, dr2, dr3], function (index, data) {
        $('#drawing' + (index + 1)).lazylinepainter({
            svgData: data,
            strokeWidth: 1.2,
            strokeColor: '#65615a',
            onComplete: function () {}
        });
    });
});
```

For the second part, use `boolean` values as Josay suggested but place the `fired` flag inside a function that returns a closure. Each call to `createPaintGuard` establishes its own `fired` flag without having to package them all into an array or object.

```
function createPaintGuard(index) {
    var fired = false;
    return function () {
        if (!fired) {
            $('#drawing' + index).lazylinepainter('paint');
            fired = true;
        }
    };
}

var drawing1 = createPaintGuard(1);
var drawing2 = createPaintGuard(2);
var drawing3 = createPaintGuard(3);
```

Note that I would probably store the three `drawingX` variables into an array instead of individually-named variables, but I have no idea how they're being used in the wider context. The code here should be a drop-in replacement for yours.

Answer (score 0):

Before removing the code repetition, let's have a look at :

```
var eventsFiredDr1 = 0;
var drawing1 = function() {
    if (eventsFiredDr1 == 0) {
        $('#drawing1').lazylinepainter('paint');
        eventsFiredDr1++; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
    }
}
```

Things would probably be clearer if you were using booleans instead of integers :

```
var eventsFiredDr1 = false;
var drawing1 = function() {
    if (!eventsFiredDr1) {
        $('#drawing1').lazylinepainter('paint');
        eventsFiredDr1 = true; //won't fire again until reload
    }
}
```

Now, to remove the duplicated code, you could create an array associating the name of the elements to their "eventsFiredDr" value :

```
drawings = { '#drawing1':false, '#drawing2':false};
```

Then you could rewrite :

```
$(window).scrollStopped(function(){
        if ($("#drawing1").is(":within-viewport")) {        
                   drawing1()
                    } 

        if ($("#drawing2").is(":within-viewport")) {      
            drawing2()
                    }

        if ($("#drawing3").is(":within-viewport")) {      
            drawing3()
                    }

        if ($("#drawing4").is(":within-viewport")) {      
            drawing4()
                    }

        if ($("#drawing5").is(":within-viewport")) {      
            drawing5()
                    }

});
```

as

```
$(window).scrollStopped(function(){
    for (drawing in drawings)
    {
        if ($(drawing).is(":within-viewport") && !drawings[drawing])
        {        
             $(drawing).lazylinepainter('paint');
             drawings[drawing] = true; // <-- now equals 1, won't fire again until reload
        }     
    }
});
```

(This is a minimalist solution, also it's not tested at all)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach (warning : untested, but i believe the concept is right).

Instead of creating a lot of different functions, we'll use a more object-oriented approach  (see below for more explanation):

```
MyLazyLinePainter = function( jqElement ){

  // first, create the lazy line painter, using svg data 
  // stored on MyLazyLinePainter's prototype
  jqElement.lazylinepainter({
    'svgData': this.svgData[ jqElement.attr('id') ],
    'strokeWidth': 1.2,
    'strokeColor': '#65615a',
    'onComplete': function () {}
  });

  // then create a painting handler, specific to this element
  var jqScope = $(window); 
  var paintHandler  = function(){
    if (jqElement.is(":within-viewport")){ 
      jqElement.lazylinepainter( 'paint' );
      // here comes the magic: the handler will remove 
      // the event listener itself when successfully executed !
      jqScope.off( 'scrollStopped', paintHandler );
    } 
  }; 

  // attach the paint handler to a window event
  jqScope.on( 'scrollStopped', paintHandler ); 
};

// extend jQuery for ease of use
$.fn.myLazyLinePainter = function(){
    return $(this).each( function(){ new MyLazyLinePainter($(this)) } );
}

// store the svg data
MyLazyLinePainter.prototype.svgData = {
  id1: // store your data here, one key for each element id
};

// here we go !
$('.myLazyLinePainter').myLazyLinePainter();
```

So, to sum up :

- each element having the class `myLazyLinePainter` will be passed to the constructor function we defined, `MyLazyLinePainter`
- the contructor attaches a `lazylinepainter` to the element. To do so, it fetches svg data from a data store, **using the element id as a key**. The data store could be anything, even something powered by AJAX queries ; you couls also (while ugly) store the data in an HTML data attribute on the element itself...
- the constructor then crafts a handler specific to the element :

  - the handler is attached to `$(window)`, and listens to the `scrollStopped` event
  - the handler, when called, checks if the element is in viewport ; if so, it triggers painting, **AND** removes itself from the `scrollStopped` listeners attached to `$(window)`, so that it fires only once.

**EDIT**

I'll attempt to clarify. There are distinct concepts introduced by this approach :

**1) use a "fire-once" event listener**

The concept here is to create one function :

```
foo = function(){ console.log('ok') }
```

...and then attach it as a handler for one event :

```
$(window).on('scroll', foo )
```

But we want this handler to **fire only once**, so the handler will remove itself from listeners :

```
var foo = function(){
  console.log('ok')
  $(window).off('scroll', foo)
}
$(window).on('scroll', foo )
```

Ok, this part is weird : we reference `foo` from inside of `foo`. As the function is a closure, we can do this : the body of the function is not evaluated yet, and *when it will be*, `foo` in its body will reference the scope the closure *encloses*, in which `foo` is a var holding the function (headaches!)

So, as soon as the function is called, `foo` is removed from the event listeners on the 'scroll' event. In practive, the event listener is just used once, and then discarded.

In my solution, it is a bit different because we only discard the listener IF the element is within viewport.

**2) use a data store**

This one is quite simple, in fact. Imagine you have :

```
 <div class="foo" id="foo1" />
 <div class="foo" id="foo2" />
```

... and so on. Now you have a data store that is a simple object :

```
 dataStore = {
   "foo1" : "data for foo1",
   "foo2" : "data for foo2"
 }

to retrieve data associated to each element, you just do :

 dataStore[ idOfTheElement ]
```

**3) extending jquery**

Ok, that one was optional. You could see `MyLazyLinePainter` as a simple function that takes a single jquery element ( as $('#foo1') ) as argument. The idea of this function is to craft specific handlers (closures) that *reference* the element that was passed as an argument. The `MyLazyLinePainter` function is called once per element grabbed by the selector i propose in the end of the solution.

Comment: I have to study this deeper, but isn't "bind" and "unbind" outdated functions ?

Comment: my bad, new syntax uses `on()` and `off()`, but the logic is the same.

Comment: note : i don't know what your `scrollStopped` event is, just assumed it was a custom event.

Comment: -> with a bit of searching, someone implemented such events : https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-events/wiki/Reference

Comment: It was a plugin, I didn't put it there because I didn't think it was relevant. I'm trying to get your code, but I begin to have a headache.

Comment: what part does hurt ? :D

Comment: I know it may seem a bit confusing, because i introduce two concepts at once : 1) using a data store for svg data 2) using a "fire-once" event

Comment: updated my answer in an attempt to clarify.